# How to empty redux store object property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I am using react redux in my app . I have different properties in object , Like

```
store: {
  users: {...}
  properties: {....}
}
```

I want to empty this `users` property from store object , I really tried hard but did not find any proper solution to resolve my problem could someone please help me how to achieve my goal .

Thanks

Comment: if you add the reducer code you have, we might be helpful in terms of particular code

Comment: To return just empty object in your reducer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your goal is, basically, to drop specific properties from your state object upon dispatching certain action, you may go for any *object filtering* techniques you fill comfortable with and put it into respective section of your reducer, E.g.:

```js
const state = {users:{user1:'prop1'}, properties:{prop1: 'value1'}},

      newState = Object
        .keys(state)
        .reduce((r,k) => 
          k != 'users' ? 
          {...r, [k]:state[k]} : 
          r, {})
        
console.log(newState)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to assign empty object to `user` reducer on `Logout` action.

Just return the empty object in reducer while fire LOGOUT_SUCCESS action. It will assign empty object to `user` reducer in store.

> userReducer.js

```
case actionTypes.LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
      return {};
```